# Botón en Navbar no se organiza por columnas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt, bulma

Estoy practicando el uso de el framweork Bulma a través de Buefy en mi proyecto de Nuxt2. Ya he trabajado alguna vez con columnas, pero sigo siendo un principiante en el desrrollo web.

Quería hacer un Navbar en mi fichero *default.vue*, que en versión móvil permita el acceso a todas las opciones mediante un menú hamburguesa que se despliega pulsando el botón *~Menú~*. La cosa es que este botón, en lugar de colocarse a la derecha del logo, se coloca justo debajo, como si el logo ocupase las 12 columnas de ancho.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nav v-if="windowWidth >= 691" class="navbar customNav columns" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <!-- NAVBAR PARA ESCRITORIO -->
    </nav>

    <nav v-else class="navbar customNav columns" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand column is-6">
        <a class="navbar-item">
          <img class="customImgSize" src="https://buefy.org/static/img/buefy.1d65c18.png">
        </a>
      </div> 
      
      <div class="navbar-start column is-6">
        <b-button class="navbar-start navbar-item" label="~Menú~"></b-button>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="main-content columns">
      <div class="container column is-12">
        <Nuxt />
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  data() {
    return {
      windowHeight: 0,
      windowWidth: 0,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeListener)
    this.resizeListener()
  },
  methods: {
    resizeListener() {
      this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight*0.6;
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth*0.9;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.customNav {
  height: 3.72rem;
  /* font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; */
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #121212;
}

.customImgSize {
  height: 3.5rem
}

.navbarLink:hover {
  color: #687c87 !important;
  background-color: white !important
}
</style>
```